# Phpstorm Reformat Code Styles

Tags: phpstorm

was wondering how do I inline php tags in .tpl files for phpstorm. For example, I would like

```
<option value="value"<?php echo $value == 'value' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
```

Instead of  the following

```
<option value="asset"
<?php echo $type == 'asset' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $text_asset; ?></option>
```

when I use the phpstorm reformat code function

Another thing is that phpstorm adds a blank line after the

```
<?php

// More codes...
```

I would like

```
<?php
// more codes...
```

Thank you :)